# How to plan your hard drives in a ZFS pool?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, filesystems, zfs

So I'm planning my hard drives for ZFS on ubuntu. One point I'm very confused is the number of hard drives that are needed to create a zpool.

Say I am creating a raidz1 with 5 hard drives. The number of hard drives required is actually 6 because I need 1 to run ubuntu and create the zpool in the other 5 drives.

But in raid (non ZFS), you actually don't need the extra hard drive for your OS and raid can be configure during installation.

So my question is, is it possible to use zfs without extra drive? Any advice or point to tutorials would be appreciated.

sources: https://pthree.org/2012/12/05/zfs-administration-part-ii-raidz/

Comment: What are your access requirements?  Depending on how time-critical access to your data is, RAID for your OS may not be important.  If the OS drive fails, you can just get a new drive, install a new copy of the OS, boot, and import the RAID ZFS pool.  Just be aware of what's stored where - important *data* goes on the RAID, things that can be reinstalled go on the single boot drive.

Comment: i see, it sounds like zfs requires an os drive. am i correct? i'm just surprised because it takes 1 sata slot.

Comment: Not necessarily - I'm not familiar enough with ZFS on Linux to know the details about making a Linux system bootable with ZFS.  But even then, I'd recommend separating your data from the OS installation.  You data needs a lot more protection than the OS install - you can recreate an OS installation easily.  You can't recreate your data.

Comment: Opinions differ as to whether to install OS on dedicated drive or directly on ZFS pool. I would personally love to put OS on ZFS pool, but I know there might be some issues with a booting process that may get broken with a update or even after replacing a drive. So I agree with @Andrew Henle and I would still like to keep OS separately from the data pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use zfs as a boot device. There is a nice little page explaining this on https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS

The trick is to NOT install ubuntu directly (that is not yet possible) but to go into "Try Linux" mode and then prepare the system from there. Once the zpool is setup, you can then install ubuntu into the new pool and also install grub to boot from it.

A word of caution: Most people who use ZFS, do so in rather large setups, where they don't care about shelling out a few bucks for extra boot disks ... and thus this process is probably not as well honed as it would be if zfs was your plain old consumer-level filesystem.

You could also just install your ubuntu on a usb stick and boot from there ...

Comment: all i can say is. gg. LOL